# STM32F2 build environment

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, stm32, freertos

Would like to get an insight on how to build an environment with FreeRTOS +LWIP on eclipse for building a specific application on STM32. What do you recommend?

Comment: This question is too broad to expect a good answer here, see [FAQ](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I'am looking for the STM32F2 port of lwip 1.4.1.
Can you help me with that? Kind Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 3):

You would need to install

- Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
- CodeSourcery Lite (ARM processors EABI Release) - a GCC toolchain for ARM
- GNU ARM Plugin for Eclipse - simplifies GCC configuration

I have a project with Eclipse Juno + CodeSourcery Lite + J-link GDB + SMTM32F4/F2 + FreeRTOS 7.3 + lwIP 1.4.1 ( PHY is KSZ8051). So if you have any specific troubles just let me know.

There is also CooCox CoIDE. It's Eclipse based and it's already preconfigured and works with J-link and ST-Link. For me the only downside was that it doesn't support C++ but only C.

Comment: How is the CodeSourcery Lite tools working for you? Do you have a good environment to develop? Any tutorial?

Comment: @HTRON : would it be possible for you to share the environment?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't FreeRTOS+LwIP, but if you used Contiki instead you'd still get all of Adam's networking code.

There is an STM32 port of Contiki.

The following isn't for STM32 but does show how to setup eclipse for another ARM platform:

```
http://mc1322x.devl.org/eclipse.md
```

Maybe it will provide some inspiration.